# How to make dependent dropdown using select2 widget yii

Tags: ajax, yii, jquery-select2-3

I want to make a dependent dropdown using select2, but i cannot change the data  for the next `dropdown($kabupaten)`, this is my code in view :

```
<?php $this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2', array(
'model' => $model,
'attribute' => 'provinsi',
'data' => $provinsi,
'htmlOptions' => array(
    'style' => 'width:440px',
    'prompt' => '-- Pilih Provinsi --',
    'ajax' => array(
        'type' => 'POST',
        'url' => CController::createUrl('Kabupaten/SelectKabupaten'),
        'class' => 'span5',
        'update' => '#' . CHtml::activeId($model, 'kabupaten'), 
    )),));
$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2', array(
  'model' => $model,
  'attribute' => 'kabupaten',
  'data' => $kabupaten,
  'htmlOptions' => array(
    'style' => 'width:440px',
    'prompt' => '-- Pilih Kabupaten --',
),));?>
```

and this is my cotroller :

```
public function actionSelectKabupaten() {
    $id_kabupaten = $_POST['DataDiriAnak']['provinsi'];
    $kabupaten = CHtml::listData(Kabupaten::model()->findByAttributes(array('IDProvinsi'=>$id_kabupaten)), 'Nama', 'Nama');
}
```

I dont know how to send value of `$kabupaten` to my last select2 dropdown

Comment: Please edit your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Sorry, i have edit my question.

Comment: You can use `onChange` event in the first dropdown

Comment: can you give me example of code please, thanks before

Answer (score 0):

You can send value of `$kabupaten` in your view by encoding data in `CHtml::tag()` as follows:

```
public function actionSelectKabupaten() {
    $id_kabupaten = $_POST['DataDiriAnak']['provinsi'];
    $kabupaten = CHtml::listData(Kabupaten::model()->findByAttributes(array('IDProvinsi'=>$id_kabupaten)), 'Nama', 'Nama');
        foreach($kabupaten as $value => $name) {
                echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $value), CHtml::encode($name), true);
        }
}
```

Let me know incase of any further query for the same.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but still doesnt work..
The data of the second select2 dropdown still empty